# While loop ending program. - Perl

Tags: perl, function, loops

This is my code, It's simple. I want to end program when someone write "end" from the commend line :)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$value = "end";

while($val = <>){
    if($value eq $val){last};
    };
```

Comment: don't forget to `chomp $val`

Comment: You should always use `use strict; use warnings;`, though it won't help find the specific error you are facing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just insert a chomp which will get rid of the newline character before comparison.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$value = "end";

while($val = <>){
    chomp $val;
    if($value eq $val){last};
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

You say you want the program to end when someone provides `end`, and that's what the code does. However, you tested by providing `end` followed by a newline. Let's accept both by removing the trailing newline if it was provided.

```
while (my $val = <>) {
    chomp($val);             <-- The relevant change
    last if $val eq 'end';
    ...
}
```